# What am i doing wrong in this code?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    typedef struct{
        char *name;
        int age;
    }person[5];

    int i;
    for (i=0;i<5;i++){
        printf ("name:");
        scanf("%s",person[i].name);
        printf("\nage:");
        scanf("%d",&person[i].age);}

    for (i=0;i<5;i++){
        printf ("person:%d",i);
        printf ("name:%s",person[i].name);
        printf ("age:%d",person[i].age);
    }
}
```

this is the sample program i have. But while compiling i keep getting the error "expected expression before person in line 10,12,16 and 17? What am i doing wrong?

Comment: If you indent your code properly, you should see the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To fix the syntax error, remove the `typedef` keyword (you're trying to declare a variable, not a type).

Better yet, change to:

```
typedef struct{
    char *name;
    int age;} Person;

Person person[5];
```

Also, the following is wrong:

```
scanf("%s",person[i].name);
```

You need to first allocate memory for `person[i].name` (for example, using `malloc()`).

Lastly, the `%s` format specifier in the following line is not correct:

```
printf ("age:%s",person[i].age);
```

Comment: fixed the %s in the question..that was a typo.
i think i get the point now..but could you explain a bit more on the memory allocation part..i think i am getting a segmentation fault due to it now

Comment: @unussunu: For the purposes of this exercise, probably the easiest thing to do is to change `char *name` to `char name[50]` (where `50` is the maximum length of the string including the NUL terminator).

Answer (score 2):

`person` is a type, not an object. You cannot "`scanf()` into a type: `person`".

I'd simply remove the typedef and just leave the struct definition outside the body of main; and create an object inside

```
struct person { /* ... */ };

int main(void) {
    struct person person[5];
    /* ... */
    return 0;
}
```